# Hololens (1st and 2nd gen) Unity App - Integrate with Azure AD

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, hololens

I'm currently working on a Unity Project for Hololens (1st and 2nd gen), our client asked us to integrate the app within the Azure AD.

We are following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/archive/blogs/appconsult/microsoft-graph-and-hololens-authentication). The code bellow doens't seem to work properly when we invoke the method **client.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes);**

```
bool authenticated = false;
PublicClientApplication client = new PublicClientApplication("*********-***-****-****-*********");
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
IEnumerable<string> Scopes = new List<string> { "User.Read"};
try
{
authResult = await client.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes);
authenticated = true;
}
catch (MsalException msaEx)
{
// Display some text like ($"Failed to acquire token: {msaEx.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
// Display some text like ($"Failed to acquire token: {ex.Message}");
}
```

For no clear reason an exception is thrown with the following message:

**- Error on deserializing read-only members in the class: No set method for property 'Claims' in type 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2ResponseBase'.**

It's not really clear for me why this exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this resolved issue: [MSAL running on HoloLens Unity app generates deserialization error: No set method for property 'Claims' in type 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2ResponseBase'](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1185)

The product team already replaced the serialization to use Newtonsoft internally to overcome these type of bugs.